# How to identify in a MVC C# Web site where my home page is loaded from ( ie calling URL)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

We have a Web site which is develop in MVC C# and we want to know how to identify where our home page is loaded from ( ie calling URL ), when it is loaded from a link which is in another web site. When someone load my home page from a specific web site I want to understand it and give him special treatment like auto login to the site.

Comment: You can't know that on you're website, you must implement a function on the others website where are the links.

Comment: You mean something like the Referer header? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referer

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13563473/asp-net-mvc-getting-calling-url

Comment: This is just a bad idea, a better design would be making use of claims issues from a mutually trusted STS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> When someone load my home page from a specific web site I want to understand it and give him special treatment like auto login to the site.

No. Nonono. No.

Of course the [referrer is already being suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32839653/how-to-identify-in-a-mvc-c-sharp-web-site-where-my-home-page-is-loaded-from-ie#comment53514299_32839653), but since that is a user-provided value you should definitely not rely on that. Anyone can set the referrer header in their browser, so anyone knowing this can log themselves in to your site.

If you control both sites, you could give a logged in user on site B (the referral site) a token that you incorporate in the link to site A. Then in site A you verify the token's validity and act accordingly.

Comment: +1 for "Anyone can set the referrer header in their browser, so anyone knowing this can log themselves in to your site"